# # and ## only can occur once in a literal string

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that character `#` and `##` only can occur once in a literal string.

It should match:

```
a#abc
a#bc##e
a##bc#e
a##e
```

But it should be non-compliant about:

```
a#a#b#c
a##bc##e
a##bc##e##d
a###e
```

Comment: Is a string where none appear considered correct?

Comment: This seems trivial to do with a simple substring match. Does it need to be a regular expression?

Comment: what is the programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regex, composed of an alternation of these two patterns:

1. `##` is matched, then a single `#` may appear
2. a single `#` is matched, then `##` may appear

```
^[^#]*(?:##[^#]*#?|#[^#]*(?:##)?)[^#]*$
```

If the regex should match strings without any `#`, just make the whole alternation optional :

```
^[^#]*(?:##[^#]*#?|#[^#]*(?:##)?)?[^#]*$
```

Comment: Good point, Thank you for your attention! 
here I want to supplement the filter condition. If the literal string is `null` or `#` and `##` don't occur once in this string, it also should be compliant.
It should also match:

Comment: @HenryChen the second regex I provided should work fine then, it can match empty strings and strings that contain no `#`

Comment: Yes, it do make sense. Thank you again! I will adopt this idea.